# Memory leak issue while downloading large number of images

Tags: objective-c, memory, memory-leaks

I am trying to downloading more then 600 images in loop with a progress meter on the top of the screen to the user. I blocked my screen with a fade layer for showing activity and progress.

I am getting the memory warning message in between and app getting crashes.

My steps to reach the loop are :

1. On app delegate, I check first core data table for all rows which is having "0" value in isImageAvailable bool field.
2. If shows me some count (say 600), and I show and alert with YES and NO option.
3. On YES : [self performSelector:@selector(myDownload:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];
4. in myDownload

   ```
   NSOperationQueue *queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
   // Create our NSInvocationOperation to call loadDataWithOperation, passing in nil 
   NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                    selector:@selector(startUpdatingRecords:) object:nil];

   // Add the operation to the queue 
   [queue addOperation:operation];
   [operation release];
   [queue release];
   ```
5. in startUpdatingRecords :

   ```
   -(void)startUpdatingRecords:(id)sender 
   {    
   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateProgressMeter:) withObject:    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.loopStartIndex]];

   // Variable declarations             
   CGSize newSizeLarge ;
   NSPredicate *predicate;
   NSMutableArray *MatchingID;
   Image_DB *data;

   // Cache Directory path
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,  YES);

   NSData *responseData; // = [[NSData alloc]init] ;

   NSURL *url = [[[NSURL alloc]init] autorelease];
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init] autorelease];
   UIImage *imgSelected_Large = [[[UIImage alloc]init] autorelease];

   // Loop through all IDs
   for (int i = 0; i < [self.arrayOfID count]; i++) //for (int i = loopStart; i < loopEnd; i++) 
   { 
   if (self.abortDownload)
   {           
       break;
   } 

   NSString *documentsDirectory = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[paths objectAtIndex:0]] autorelease];
   documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
   documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/ImageFolder"]; // Image folder path

   myClass *classObj = [self.arrayOfID objectAtIndex:i];   

   NSString *strURl = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", self.MyURL,recipeObj.recipeImageStr] autorelease];
   //NSLog(@"URL = %@",strURl);           

   url = [NSURL URLWithString:strURl];
   request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:NULL error:NULL]; // Get Image Data into NSData

   //imgSelected_Large = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURl]]];

   NSLog(@"Download Count = %d",i+1);

   if (responseData != nil)
   {
       imgSelected_Large = [UIImage imageWithData:responseData];

       // Resizining image
       newSizeLarge.width = 320;    
       newSizeLarge.height = 180;     

       imgSelected_Large = [self imageWithImage:imgSelected_Large scaledToSize:newSizeLarge]; // New sized image
       NSData *dataPhoto; // no need to release it because UIImageJPEGRepresentation gives autoreleased NSData obj.
       dataPhoto  = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgSelected_Large, 0.6);  // Set new image representation and its Compression Quality

       documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image_%d", classObj.nodeID]];            
       [dataPhoto writeToFile:documentsDirectory atomically:YES]; //Write file to local folder at default path

       predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"(image_ID = %d )",recipeObj.nodeID];
       MatchingID = [CoreDataAPIMethods searchObjectsInContext:@"Image_DB" :predicate :@"image_ID" :YES :self.managedObjectContext];

       // Setting flag variable for available image
       for (int j = 0; j< [MatchingID count]; j++)
       {
           //Assign the Authors Records in Class Object and save to Database 
           data = (Image_DB*) [MatchingID objectAtIndex:j];                
           // data.image_large = dataPhoto; // Code for storing BLOB object to DB
           data.extra_1 = @"1";
           //NSLog(@"Flag updated");
       }
   }
   // Exit out code
   if ( i == [self.arrayOfID count] - 1 || i == [self.arrayOfID count]) // Its the last record to be stored
   {    
       NSError *error;             
       if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
       {
           // Handle the error...
           NSLog(@"Error in updating %@",error);
       } 

       self.isUpdateImageCalled = NO;
       [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeProgressMeter) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

   }
   // Update UI screen while in downloading process
   [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateProgressMeter:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",self.loopStartIndex+i+1]];
   }
   }
   ```

If I didn't release responseData then my app shows me memory warning and got crashed. If I released then, [NSConcreteMutableData release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1e931de0 error occures.

How to refine my code. Can any one suggest me on my code and rework and make a refined code.

Please please help me out.

Comment: May this link can help you out !!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3703734/downloading-large-amount-of-images-ipad-memory-leak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `responseData` returned by `sendSynchronousRequest` is autoreleased thus you shouldn't release it yourself. For the first sight I don't see a memory leak in your code. It is possible that your application *actually* uses too much memory, without leaking it. Try to place an autorelease pool inside your for cycle:

```
for (...) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    // your original code with a lot of autoreleased objects

    [pool release];
}
```

If you wrap your code within an autorelease pool, *all* objects that are sent the `autorelease` message inside the wrap will be actually released when the pool itself is released: this way you purge the memory in every for cycle.

See also [Using Autorelease Pools](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html) in the doc, it specifically mentions that you should use them in the case "if you write a loop that creates many temporary objects".